# setting column to datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, format, type-conversion

The date in my dataset is like this: 20130501000000 and I'm trying to convert this to a better datetime format in R

```
data1$date <- as.Date(data1$date, format = "%Y-%m-%s-%h-%m-%s")
```

However, I get an error for needing an origin. After I put the very first cell under date in as origin, it converts every cell under date to N/A. Is this right or should I try as.POSIXct()?

Answer (score 13):

That is a somewhat degenerate format, but the `anytime()` and `anydate()` functions of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package can help you, without requiring any explicit format strings:

```
R> anytime("20130501000000")       ## returns POSIXct
[1] "2013-05-01 CDT"
R> anydate("20130501000000")       ## returns Date
[1] "2013-05-01"
R>
```

Not that we parse from character representation here -- parsing from numeric would be wrong as we use a conflicting heuristic to make sense of dates stored a numeric values.

So here your code would just become

```
data1$data <- anytime::anydate(data1$date)
```

provided `data1$date` is in character, else wrap one `as.character()` around it.

Lastly, if you actually want Datetime rather than Date (as per your title), don't use `anydate()` but `anytime()`.

Comment: You are welcome.  Please feel free "accept" (click on tickmark) and/or "upvote" (click on up-arrow) if the answer fits your question.

Answer (score 0):

Before I write my answer, I would like to say that the `format` argument should be **the format that your string is in**. Therefore, if you have `"20130501000000"`, you have to use (you don't have `-` between each component of your date in the string format):

```r
as.Date("20130501000000", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# [1] "2013-05-01"
```

which works just fine, does not produce any error, and will return an object of class `Date`:

```r
as.Date("20130501000000", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") |> class()
# [1] "Date"
```

Therefore, I think your issue is more of a formatting and not origin of the date.

---

Now to my detailed answer:

As far as I know and can understand, the `as.Date()` will convert it to "date", so if you want the time part of the string as well, you have to use `as.POSIXct()`:

```r
as.POSIXct("20130501000000", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# [1] "2013-05-01 EEST"

as.POSIXct("20130501000000", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") |> class()
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Note that the timezone is `EEST` which is **my local timezone**, if you want to define the timezone, you have to define it. For example to set the timezone to UTC:

```r
as.POSIXct("20130501000000", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tz = "UTC")
# [1] "2013-05-01 UTC"
```

using the `as.POSIXct()` you can do arithmetic with the object:

```r
times <- c("20130501000000",
           "20130501035001") # added 03:50:01 to the first element
class(times)
# [1] "character"

times <- as.POSIXct(times, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tz = "UTC")
class(times)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

times[2] - times[1]
# Time difference of 3.833611 hours
```